# Angular service worker is not registering after it is unregistered

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I have added Angular service worker in an existing application using the following command

```
ng add @angular/pwa
```

after that, i have built the application and run the application. At first, it shows the service worker but i unregister it manually. After that, i tried to build it again. But the service worker is not getting installed again.

May i know how to register the service worker again in the Angular application?

App.module.ts

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
      enabled: environment.production,
      // Register the ServiceWorker as soon as the app is stable
      // or after 30 seconds (whichever comes first).
      registrationStrategy: 'registerImmediately',
    }),
```

ngsw-config.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Even i created a new application and installed service worker and unregister the service worker after first build after that the service worker is not registered again.

service worker used

```
"@angular/service-worker": "^12.2.8",
```

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: @johannesMatevosyan No, i didn't get an solution for it yet

Answer (score 0):

Do you have in angular.json:

`"serviceWorker": true`

It should be in architect -> options.

Comment: it is available in angular.json